# How to execute a url and parse it from bash shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

I am working on a project in which I need to make a url call to one of my server from the bash shell script..

```
http://hostname.domain.com:8080/beat
```

After hitting the above url, I will be getting the below response which I need to parse it and extract value of `syncs` and `syncs_behind`

```
state: READY num_retries_allowed: 3 syncs: 30 syncs_behind: 100 num_rounds: 60 hour_col: 2 day_col: 0 oldest_day_col: 0
```

Now I need to hit the above url every 10 seconds for a period of 10 minutes and extract the value of `syncs` and `syncs_behind` from it and use to validate it with below condition -

```
syncs > 8
syncs_behind = 0
```

if the syncs is greater than 8 and syncs_behind = 0, then I will end my shell script with some message saying - "Data has been validated", otherwise I would keep on trying for 10 minute window.. If in that 10 minute window, this doesn't happen I will end the shell script anyway meaning I won't retry again.

So I started with the below code but got stuck, what should I do to parse the data coming from the URL -

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -O - -q -t 1 http://hostname.domain.com:8080/beat
```

I am not familiar with shell script that much so after reading it I came to know about wget.. There might be some better way of doing it..

Any thoughts how this can be done?

**UPDATE:-**

I saved the file as `beat.sh` with the below contents –

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNT=60   #number of 10 second timeouts in 10 minutes
SUM_SYNCS=0
SUM_SYNCS_BEHIND=0

while [[ $COUNT -ge "0" ]]; do

#send the request, put response in variable
DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://hostname.domain.com:8080/beat)

#grep $DATA for syncs and syncs_behind
SYNCS=$(echo $DATA | grep -o 'syncs:: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')
SYNCS_BEHIND=$(echo $DATA | grep -o 'syncs_behind: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')
echo $SYNCS
echo $SYNCS_BEHIND

#add new values to the sum totals
let SUM_SYNCS+=SYNCS
let SUM_SYNCS_BEHIND+=SYNCS_BEHIND

#verify conditionals
if [[ $SYNCS -gt "8" -a $SYNCS_BEHIND -eq "0" ]]; then exit -1; fi

#decrement the counter
let COUNT-=1

#wait another 10 seconds
sleep 10

done
```

And when I am running it as `./beat.sh`, I got below error -

```
./beat.sh: line 23: syntax error in conditional expression
./beat.sh: line 23: syntax error near `-a'
./beat.sh: line 23: `if [[ $SYNCS -gt "8" -a $SYNCS_BEHIND -eq "0" ]]; then exit -1; fi'
```

Any thoughts what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: crosspost: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118501/how-to-execute-a-url-and-parse-it-from-bash-shell-script

Comment: closed that one as I was not sure which site is suited for these type of quesiton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

great start! Let's break it down:

```
COUNT=60   #number of 10 second timeouts in 10 minutes
SUM_SYNCS=0
SUM_SYNCS_BEHIND=0

while [[ $COUNT -ge "0" ]]; do

#send the request, put response in variable
DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://hostname.domain.com:8080/beat)

#grep $DATA for syncs and syncs_behind
SYNCS=$(echo $DATA | grep -oE 'syncs: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')
SYNCS_BEHIND=$(echo $DATA | grep -oE 'syncs_behind: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')

#add new values to the sum totals
let SUM_SYNCS+=SYNCS
let SUM_SYNCS_BEHIND+=SYNCS_BEHIND

#verify conditionals
if [[ $SYNCS -gt "8" && $SYNCS_BEHIND -eq "0" ]]; then exit -1; fi

#decrement the counter
let COUNT-=1

#wait another 10 seconds
sleep 10

done
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. In my example I would need to verify if the sync > 8 and sync_behind = 0 then only I will break out of my shell script.. When they both are true.. And in your example you are verifying only syncs I guess.

Comment: Sure.. And also why are you adding these? `#add new values to the sum totals
let SUM_SYNCS+=SYNCS
let SUM_SYNCS_BEHIND+=SYNCS_BEHIND` Is there any particular reason? I just need to verify on my condition whether syncs > 8 and sync_behind = 0 or not?

Comment: And also when I ran your code, I tried printing out SYNCS and SYNCS_BEHIND and it is not getting printed out somehow.. It is coming as empty.. Any thoughts what is wrong?

Comment: There were couple of issues which I have fixed it by editing it.. You need extra `E` option for extended regex to use with [0-9] and bash doesn't support `-a` option. So you need to use `&&` instead of `-a`

Comment: @problemPotato: Can you explain whether we need `#add new values to the sum totals
let SUM_SYNCS+=SYNCS
let SUM_SYNCS_BEHIND+=SYNCS_BEHIND` or not?

Comment: Nope - I had mis-interpreted your question. If you don't need to keep a running total, then you can just check the values of $SYNCS and $SYNCS_BEHIND directly!

Comment: One last thing, I would like to exit from the shell script successfully if the condition is met within ten minutes or if the condition is not met after 10 minutes.. So exit -1 is successful exit? Why I am asking this is bcoz I will be calling this shell script from Python program.

Comment: @problemPotato: Can you help me on my last question if possible?

Comment: The while loop breaks when $COUNT hits 0. Count is initialized to 60 and decrements each time the loop iterates. Each loop iteration includes a 10 second sleep. 10*60 = 600 seconds or 10 minutes! If the other conditional is triggered then the code as written will exit the script with -1, but you can feel free to change that return code to whatever you'd like!

Comment: @problemPotato: Sure. In general if I would like to exit successfully from shell script then I should be using exit 0.. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Not a c&p ready solution, but hopefully something to get you started:

You want to redirect the output of `wget` into a file, and then use a combination of `awk` and `sed` to extract the parts that you are actually interested in. You'll probably need a few minutes and '*hello worlds*' with both commands, but it well worth the effort.

In terms of retrying / exiting, you probably need an endless loop with an `if` statements that evaluates the exit conditions. For time control I'd play with the `sleep` command, even though `crontab` might be an alternative worthwhile considering.

I'd recommend to focus on the first part (parsing and evaluating) and maybe raise a new question once you're ready to move on...